# how to prevent duplicate entry for creating cron jobs?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, cron, cron-task

here the below code for creating cron jobs successfully but i need to prevent duplicate entry so next time i'm trying to create cron jobs for same file. i need to overwrite existing cron jobs

```
 #!/bin/bash
    crontab -l > cd3.new
    file1="/home/admin/Desktop/n_com.sh -EI"
    file2="/home/admin/Desktop/com.sh -NI"
    file3="/home/admin/Desktop/fcom.sh -EF"
    file4="/home/admin/Desktop/fcm.sh -NF"
    echo "$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $file1" >> cd3.new
    echo "$6 $7 $8 $9 ${10} $file2" >> cd3.new
    echo "${11} ${12} ${13} ${14} ${15} $file3" >> cd3.new
    echo "${16} ${17} ${18} ${19} ${20} $file4" >> cd3.new
    cat cd3.new
    crontab cd3.new
```

Comment: Then you can store the current and the old in different files and play with `diff`.

Comment: @fedorqui i need to overwrite

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of setting up directories for each "period" of cron, and using [run-parts](http://man.cx/run-parts%288%29) to execute them.    Updating just requires rsync-ing the new cron directories and there's no chance of messing up crontabs.

And then I setup directories and a crontab as such:

```
# Run hourly, daily, weekly, monthly and yearly tasks for axon
00  0 * * * run-parts /etc/cron/midnight >/dev/null 2>&1
01  * * * * run-parts /etc/cron/hourly   >/dev/null 2>&1
02  1 * * * run-parts /etc/cron/daily    >/dev/null 2>&1
55 23 * * * run-parts /etc/cron/dailyend >/dev/null 2>&1
45  2 * * 6 run-parts /etc/cron/weekly   >/dev/null 2>&1
02  0 1 * * run-parts /etc/cron/monthly  >/dev/null 2>&1
03  0 1 1 * run-parts /etc/cron/yearly   >/dev/null 2>&1
```